# Unable to download dynamic image in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

hey i am creating a app in which dynamic images should be download from the net but some cant able to download kindly check the code below and give some suggestion to download and also tell how to pass dynamic image link in social share plugin in ngcordova .

```
 $

scope.downloadImage = function() {
            $http.get('http://sabkideal.com/phpapi_/cashback.php').success(function(response) {
      $scope.data = response;

       for (var i=0 ;i <response.length; i++)
       {
        var url = response[i].image;
        var deal = response[i].id;
        //url showing the same url every time i click and not jumping to next statement when click on send image download .
       console.log(deal);

      console.log(url);

      var filename = url.split("/").pop  ;

 console.log(filename);

      var     targetPath = encodeURI(cordova.file.dataDirectory + fileName);
       console.log(targetPath);

    var   options = {};
       var  trustHosts = true;

        }


                $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
      .then(
        function(result) {
          alert('Download success');
          refreshMedia.refresh(targetPath);
        },
        function(err) {
          alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        },
        function(progress) {
          // progressing download...
        })

});


     }
```